# How to allocate unallocated space of hard disk in Ubuntu 12.4 after installation

Tags: partitioning, unallocated

How to allocate unallocated space of hard disk in Ubuntu 12.04 after installation.

My system is running fine with Windows and Linux. I am using Windows rarely and for my official purpose I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

I forgot to allocate around 100 GB of space while installing. Now 100 GB is free in HDD and its not usable.

How can I allocate that free space as another volume without formatting the current OS?

Comment: Can you add an image of the Gparted screen?  Upload it add the link, and I'll add it for you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you can do:

1. Start a Terminal session by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type `gksudo gparted` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type your password in the window that pops up
4. Find the partition Ubuntu is installed in. If you are unsure what it is, type `sudo df` in a Terminal session and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The filesystem mounted on / will be the Ubuntu partition.
5. Right-click the partition and select Resize/Move
6. Expand the Ubuntu partition into the unallocated space
7. Profit!

Comment: I should make it clearer that this must be done from a live cd if you are resizing the system partition.

Answer (score 2):

Search and open "disks" in the dash, then click the disk on the left and click the plus underneath the partitions to add a new one. Change the type to FAT for compatibility on windows, name it and click ok, then you're done!

Comment: what if they are running headless ?

Comment: If you're running headless, `man parted`.